# How to get a specific number position on the list?

Tags: python, list

Is there a method to retrieve the number position in the list?
For example, in the following code, can we get the maximum number position?

```
a = [1, 2, 10, 5]
    
print(index_max(a))
# 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the index method:

```
a.index(max(a)) # 2
```

Or, if your list is long and you don't want to go through it twice, you can use the key parameter of the max function:

```
max(range(len(a)),key=lambda i:a[i]) # 2
```

This finds the maximum index (from `range(len(a))`) but uses an indirection to determine how to compare the index.  So the comparison is based on the value at each index instead of the index itself.  The result is the index that has the highest value.

for details on the max() function see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max

Comment: `max(range(len(a)),key=lambda i:a[i])` is brilliant but deserves a bit of explanation

Comment: `a.argmax()` would give the index of the highest value directly if `a` is a numpy array.

Comment: @dawg The first parameter of `max` is the list of elements to iterate through. `max` has an optional key parameter, which is a function that takes the value of the element in the list and returns a number that can be used for comparison. The value returned by that function will be used to determine which element has the max in the list. After determining the max element using the key function, `max` returns that element. The first parameter passed to max is `range(len(a))` which returns a list from 0 to len(a) -1, which is the indices of the list a.

Comment: @dawg The key function is simply getting the value at the index `i` from the the list `a` . So it uses the value to decide the max element from the first parameter passed to `max`, which happens to be the indices of the list `a`. Does that make sense?

Comment: I did not mean to explain to *me* I meant add to the *answer*

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `index` method:

```
a.index(max(a))
```

Another possibility, is using `enumerate`:

```
>>> max(enumerate(a), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
(2, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
>>> print(a.index(max(a)))
2
```

So you are priting the index-position in list of the maximum number

Answer (score 0):

Python has an inbuilt function called `index()`,  which can be used to obtain the index position of an element in a list. In this instance, you may write `a.index(max(a))`.

Comment: Sorry I'm on my phone and it's difficult to type code blocks :(

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one value that might be the `max` you can use `enumerate`:

```
a = [1, 2, 10, 5, 10, 6]

>>> [i for i,x in enumerate(a) if x==max(a)]
[2, 4]
```

Or, if you want the value included:

```
>>> [(i,x) for i,x in enumerate(a) if x==max(a)]
[(2, 10), (4, 10)]
```